# EDGAR RESTful API dei taxonomy

Tags: json, taxonomy, xbrl, edgar

I'm trying to write a Microsoft Excel UDF to pull information from the U.S. SEC's EDGAR database.  The documentation I can find says that I can pull data (for example) this way, and I'll get a JSON response:

https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyconcept/CIK##########/us-gaap/AccountsPayableCurrent.json

This works, as long as the taxonomy is "us-gaap", but I would have assumed that if I needed something from the "dei" taxonomy, I would just change that section of the URI, but no dice.  For example, a company quarterly filing would have, on its cover page, its ticker symbol, which is in the dei taxonomy as "TickerSymbol".  This, however, doesn't work

https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyconcept/CIK##########/dei/TickerSymbol.json

Anybody have experience trying to get this data out?  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I've been banging my head on this too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept that you are after is called `TradingSymbol` not `TickerSymbol`.  Have a look at this Microsoft filing and search for "Symbol":

https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459022026876/msft-10k_20220630.htm

It appears that the concept is reported using a dimensional breakdown so that it is reported for each class of share, and unfortunately, it appears that facts with dimensions are not included in the `data.sec.gov` data.  I can't find any documentation to this effect, but if I look at all facts for the company using this view, I can't find any dimensionally qualified facts:

https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0000789019.json

Given the amount of facts in a typical filing that are dimensionally qualified, this seems like quite an omission.

You might like to take a look at the XBRL US API, which I know does include all facts:

https://xbrl.us/home/use/xbrl-api/

Comment: Thanks.  That's a great resource.  It popped up in a few searches, but I didn't investigate it thoroughly.  I guess I'm back to parsing the entire filing instead of using the API.  That is less than ideal.

Comment: Why do you say that?  Does your usage fall outside the free tier for the XBRL US API?

Comment: Probably not.  I guess I just have to bite the bullet and figure out how to use XBRL US API.  I was trying to do it directly with sec.gov.